# How make Qt app not append D when trying to linking to my library

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qmake, debug-symbols

I have a Qt app & a few libraries built using .pro file in each. When building for windows, I want to build my app in debug mode & hence link to debug versions of my libraries. All if this here is static linking. I build the debug versions of my libraries. All fine. pdb files also generated in the build folder.

But when I build my app it complains of the following error appending a `D` to my library name !!!

`error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyLibD.lib'`

It should be looking for MyLib.lib not MyLibD.lib as I specifying below in MyApp.pro. Following is how I link to my library in MyApp.pro

```
LIBS           += -L$$MyLib_build_location -lMyLib
Release:win32: LIBS += -L$$MyLib_build_location -lMyLib
Debug:win32: LIBS += -L$$MyLib_build_location -lMyLib
INCLUDEPATH    += $$MyLib_include_location/
DEPENDPATH     += $$MyLib_include_location/
unix:PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$MyLib_build_location/MyLib.a
Release:win32:PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$MyLib_build_location/MyLib.lib
Debug:win32:PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$MyLib_build_location/MyLib.lib
```

**Why is windows OS expecting my library to be appended with `D` when in debug mode ? How can make Qt look for the same name as `TARGET` specified in library´s .pro ?**

Note that, I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition along Qt Creator for the C++ compiler

Comment: Why do you need all those duplicates linker flags?

Comment: May be I don't need all of that. Just trying all means to get rid of the issue. Any suggestions on how I can link to the debug versions of my library ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg simplifying it to not have the Release & Debug appended also gets the same error. Not sure how to fix this. Really need some suggestions pls

Comment: I added `win32:CONFIG += no_lflags_merge` which gets rid of this error. but now it complains of the following error.     `error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj` Is there some way I can fix this ? Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: One shall not mix debug and release libraries on static builds using older compilers and cannot mix them on up-to-date compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building a debug build of your application: it needs to link with debug libraries! You need to fix the project files for the libraries so that the debug build is available, with the correct prefix.

Also note that the manual tweaking of build locations is usually counterproductive.